# postmeta caches in wordpress and updates after viewing edit page

Tags: wordpress, caching

I have a problem. i need bach find/replace in postmeta table, so i use phpmyadmin to do this.
changes are accepted by database, but not in wp (seems that its cached)
there is no cache plugin installed.
when i go to editing post in wp-admin, cache refreshes the postmeta content and i could see the changes in vewing post.
how could i manually refresh this cache?
if a caching system is installed on server, doese it affects on phpmyadmin results too? couse changes could be seen there.

note: exactly this cms works fine on local.
thx

Comment: You try this for removing cache: http://example.com/?123 and enter to remove all the cache.

Comment: yup, tried to add query str after it, it doesnt works

Comment: Check this thing too after the user is login.

Answer (score 0):

The postmeta cache is part of the WordPress core. It works even if you have no cache plugin.

Opening up some item (any item will do) in the Media Library for edit, then saving it, will flush that cache.